# Add action to return key for UITextField inside a TableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I read many tutorials to add an action to return key on the keyboard in `UITextField`, but none of them help me to add action when `UITextField` is inside the `TableViewCell`. Should I manage it in the `Cell class` or in the `cellForRowAt`function? could you help me on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a UITextFieldDelgate added to your UITextField in which you can override the function textFieldShouldReturn where you could perform your actions for return key.

Check out this for reference. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn

Comment: thanks, I know that, but I don't know where should I do that? in the class of tableviewCell or in the cellForRowAt? If it should be done in cellForRowAt, how it should be done?

Comment: You should not do that in TableViewCell class as same instances of cells could be reused. It should be done in the cellForRowAt function. You will have an instance of your table view cell over there and you could access your textfield from the cell object if you had an outlet for it. May be make your UITableView conforms to UITextfieldDelegate and set like textfield.delegate = self in cellforrowat function.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can use textFieldShouldReturn function inside cellForRowAt

Comment: Thanks I understand now what you mean